# easiest way to implement alternating row colors?

Tags: theming

DISCLAIMER,

I am not a programmer.

What would be the easiest way to implement alternating css row colors in a table for a drupal 7 theme?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To augment @Clive's answer, drupal also adds a CSS class of "odd" and "even" to each TR element in the default theme table, so you could use them, too, eg:

```
tr.odd { background-color: #ccc; }
tr.even { background-color: #aaa; }
```

These are based on the `$zebra` variable that is available in a lot of templates just for this purpose.

Comment: Forgot about that!...it's great for tables that run through `theme_table()` but it might not catch everything...safest thing would probably be to add both sets of rules, then all bases are covered

Comment: safest would be to banish IE < 9 but don't get me started there :)

Comment: This type of row classing is so inefficient, we already have so many ids, classes, wrappers; Go with elegant CSS (I know Drupal adds those alternating classes anyway, I just dont like it)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way would be straight CSS using the [`:nth-child` pseudo-selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild):

```
tr:nth-child(even) td { background: #ccc; }
tr:nth-child(odd) td { background: #aaa; }
```

The usual caveats apply (i.e. it doesn't work in Internet Explorer <9)